# When setting a variable in python, why does the order matter?

Tags: python, syntax

```
def calculate_error(m, b, point):
    x_point, y_point = point  
    y = m*x_point + b
    distance = abs(y-y_point)
    return distance

print(calculate_error(2, 0, (5, 5)))
```

I ran the code above and it worked. But I do not understand why it doesn't work when I tried setting point = x_point, y_point instead?

Comment: x_point, y_point is what you've used? Isn't it?

Comment: yes. That's is correct.

Comment: Questions specific to python are off-topic here, unfortunately. You can try your luck at [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most programming languages, the `=` operator is an *assignment operator* which *assigns* to the left the *values* on the right.

Sometimes there are variations on the semantics, but it rarely means *equal*.

Coincidentally, though, which may cause confusion, after `x = y`, that is, after `x` has been assigned the value of `y`, the two values are equal, denoted in many languages (including Python) with `x == y`.

Hence, if you write

```
y = 3
y = x
```

the program crashes because `x` hasn't been given a value.